# Particles fall through collision object

Tags: particles, collision

I am trying to make leaves fall on the ground but the leaves are intersecting the ground.

This is the collision floor seen from under:

[image]

The object has collision enabled and Particle Damping to the max. I've played around with different settings but couldn't find one that worked.
I haven't been able to find a similar question here where the particles are falling onto the object...

[image]

Comment: Have you applied (Ctrl+A) the collision object's scale? I've had that cause physics collisions issues recently.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid particles to intersect with the ground, check Size Deflect checkbox in particle system Physics settings. This is not a perfect solution either, cause the particles will hover over the ground plane a little, so what you can do is to use this plane as collision box, which won't be rendered and it's duplicate without collision added, which you move closer/furhter away to the particles and which will be rendered. If you need even more physically accurate interactions between leaves and a plane, you would need to use separate objects (which can be created from particles by Shift+CTRL+A) and make them rigid bodies.

Comment: Do you mean to make the particles rigid bodies? Or after they have been emitted?

Comment: After they've been emitted.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid particles getting through, make sure you have thickness on your floor or object. That's all.